# change mac xampp htdocs to SDcard?

Tags: macos, xampp, sd-card

I got a MAC.  I installed XAMPP as I did in Windows.  It works.  But how do I change the htdocs folder to the SDcard?

I opened the Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf
found the DirectoryRoot line
Tried to change as follow:

```
<Directory "/Volumes/SDcard/xampp/htdocs">
<Directory "/SDcard/xampp/htdocs">
```

both settings keep showing "Access forbidden!"
but the folder info said "You can read and write"

then I add a symbolic link in Applications/XAMPP/

```
ln -s /Volumes/SDcard/xampp/htdocs ./htdocs-sdard
```

and change the httpd.conf again

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs-sdcard">
```

it does not work either.  same error page

Any ideas?

I also want to change the MySQL folder to SDcard too.....  :(

Answer (score 0):

I just found I need to change DocumentRoot too.

```
DocumentRoot "/Volumes/SDcard64G/xampp/htdocs" 
<Directory "/Volumes/SDcard64G/xampp/htdocs">
```

Now it works